# RequestQueue In Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have doubt in the code provided in documentation for Sending A Simple Request.

```
 val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://www.google.com"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
            textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

In this code first A Request is being made to the url and then the stringRequest is getting stored in the Queue. My doubt is that on making the request we will get a response,  then what is the need of storing it the Queue and then rerunning all the operations like Checking in Cache Memory etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following statement you tell the runtime what kind of request you want to make.

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })
```

The request will not be executed immediately. In order to have it executed, it has to be added to the request queue.

In other words: if you remove the following line

```
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

the request will not be made at all.

These lines from the [guide on Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#send) summarize how it works (emphasis mine)

> To send a request, you simply construct one and add it to the RequestQueue with add(), as shown above. **Once you add the request it moves through the pipeline**, gets serviced, and has its raw response parsed and delivered.